# UICollectionViewCell - Edit mode

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on an app in which i've implemented edit mode in `UICollectionView`.I am trying to implement something like this :

[image]

when i click on edit button,camera button and eye button should get hidden and delete and rename button should appear like this :

[image]

And after editing,when i click on "Done" button,delete button and rename button should get hidden and camera button and eye button should get appeared again. I've tried it but it is giving me some weird output. Everything is working fine except this "edit" button functioning. Can anyone suggest me any way to resolve this. Suggestions will be appreciated. Please provide some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "edit" button functioning?

Comment: can any one help me regarding this????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your explanation about your task,you have filled this collection
view by an `NSMutableArray`. So you can achieve your task by filling all
button on their respective `UICollectionViewCell` using array of delete
images ,array of rename images,array of camera images and array of eye
images . Just set flag for each particular condition.And when you click on
'edit' button,  on the basis of that flag ,you can fill your collection
view. Just try this. It might help you.

Comment: That is really amazing !! I just needed to reload my collectionview on edit button click after implementing this logic. Your idea solved my problem..